# Transparent lines for a hologram like effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I have a hologram like effect in the Cycles render engine. And so far I'm satisfied with the results.
[image]

And my node setup is this ("Emission" shader and "Transparent" shader are mixed together by a "Layer Weight" node in the "Factor" value of the "Mix Shader" - 
[image]

However, is there a way to create those transparent lines that when animated go upwards like in many sci-fi movies? Something like this - 
[image]

Comment: David's answer works for me now, but lets say that the object was rigged and animated, is there a way for lines to travel at the direction of the Z normal of some projector of the hologram regardless of the animation of the object? This is what I mean by a "projector" (the sphere like object is projected by a projector [the object underneath it]) - http://www.digibuzzme.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/blender_3d_hologram_by_logichy.jpg

Comment: Lets say that the floor in the first image above is the projector of the hologram. Is there a way for the lines to travel at the direction of the Z normal of the floor regardless of the animation of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Cycles nodes]
I used a *Checker Texture* to make the lines, adjust the *scale* to make the thickness of the lines you want. The *Mapping* node's *Scale* along the Y and X to 0, stretches out the checker texture to make it a line. Then the *Location* along the Z is animated to make the lines move. 
Replace the two *Emission* nodes for your hologram shader.

Comment: Thanks. I tried something. Is this ok, or I'm missing something? - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31537

Comment: Also if possible, is there a way for the transparent part to be not completely transparent?

Comment: @Vladimir http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31538 take a look at what I did to the nodes.

Comment: Thanks (pretty easy actually). Just one last thing - Lets say the hologram (monkey) was projected by the floor underneath it, is there a way for the lines to be aligned with it (the lines to move upwards according to the Z normal of the floor)? ('cause that's why I needed the effect in the first place)

Comment: sounds like you would want to UV *project from View (Bounds)* to get all the UV aligned, then just stretch out the texture again.