# How can I hide hidden topology with a hologram shader?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, emission

I have a hologram shader that is mapped out like this in Eevee 2.9:

[image]

I've tried toggling Backface culling and other options. However, I still have a good of unseen topology being rendered through my hologram material:

[image]

How can I minimize this in the material?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **Cycles**

*Light Path* > **Transparent Depth**

[image]

### **Eevee**

*Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode >* **Alpha Blend**
**Show Backface** > OFF

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/transparent-lines-for-a-hologram-like-effect

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks :) Updated.