# How can I hide the interior/parts behind while the whole fox is still transparent?

Tags: transparency, emission

Below is the fox, with the top just the clay view and the bottom the render. The material used is just an emission and transparent shader, controlled with a fresnel with the IQR cranked really close to 1, and some extra details on the head.

As you can see with the render below, because none of the objects are merged together, you can see both the rig mistakes in the neck area and the outlines of every object showing through. Is it possible to hide these? what I am hoping for is essentially for the fox to still be transparent, but only the outline and the markings show. I do realize I can use an outline, but from what I understand, that is only in eevee, and I still want the emission from the fox. In addition, I want the outline to be pretty thin, which is why I used the fresnel.
[image]

Comment: keyword "hologram" -> similar questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/200274/107598 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/262144/107598

Comment: Have you considered Line Art  or Freestyle instead? the 2D treatment takes occlusion into account, and can be stylized

Comment: @Blunder That was exactly it, thank you so much!